# how to fetch local json file from a child folder of src using fetch in react typescript app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For a particular functionality, the backend part is not yet done in the application I am working on. So, I am trying to fetch the content of a local JSON file (to mock fetching an HTTP response) placed in a child of the src folder. How should I fetch the file correctly? I am not getting anything in `response.json().` (Note: I don't want to move it to the public folder)

Here is what I have tried so far: https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-noether-b5dj8k?file=/src/App.tsx:273-277

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the relevant code in your question, not (only) a link to an external page

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by that?

Comment: I am not able to post the code because I need to add a file under a different folder. So, I attached the sandbox link

Comment: @KamenMinkov I updated the question. Please check

Comment: @Whiz I don't think you will be able to do so. you will need to import the file if it's a local JSON file into your app.js file and use it. but if you needed to make fake APIs and practice on them. you will need to make the external application and it will achieve what you need to make a fetch call

Comment: @Amryasser :( in public folder it was working. I know it is hosting the file but I thought there should be some alternate as in some sites they were doing like fetch("./data.json")

Comment: @Whiz from what I have seen, to be honest. if you're going to use a local JSON file. you will just import it into your component. I don't know to be honest if it's going to work with fetch() or not. I did some research also. but they import the file into their component. If you wanted another way also I can share it with you. I made a fake JSON API and used fetch() with it. things worked perfectly.

Comment: is there any way to mock the HTTP request by importing or manually returning like response: { body: Readable Stream } etc like that?

Comment: it depends on the way that you're using it. for your way which is a local JSON file, you will then import that file into your component and use it without making a fetch into it. then you won't need to take the response of it. another way is that you make a JSON server and you will use the fetch() method to get the data. and you will take the response from it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245901/discussion-between-whiz-and-amr-yasser).